# automatic redirection of functions

Tags: r

The language is R.

I have a couple of files:

```
utilities.non.foo.R
utilities.foo.R
utilities.R
```

`foo` is an in-house package that has been cobbled together (for image processing, although this is irrelevant). It works great, but only on Linux machines, and it is a huge pain to try and compile it even on those.

Basically, `utilities.foo.R` contains a whole lot of functions that require package `foo`. 
The functions in here are called `functionname.foo`.

I'm about to start sharing this code with external collaborators who don't have this package or Linux, so I've written a file `utilities.non.foo.R`, which contains all the functions in `utilities.foo.R`, except the dependency on package `foo` has been removed.
These functions are all called `functionname.non.foo`.

The file `utilities.R` has a whole heap of this, for each function:

```
functionname <- function(...) {
    if ( fooIsLoaded() ) {
        functionname.foo(...)
    } else {
        functionname.non.foo(...)
    }
}
```

The idea is that one only needs to load `utilities.R` and if you happen to have package `foo` (e.g. my internal collaborators), you will use that backend. If you *don't* have `foo` (external collaborators), you'll use the non-foo backend.

**My question is: is there some way to do the redirection for each function name without explicitly writing the above bit of code for every single function name?**

This reminds me of how (e.g.) there is a `print` method, a `print.table`, `print.data.frame`, etc, but the user only needs to use `print` and which method is used is chosen automatically.

I'd like to have that, except the `method.class` would be more like `method.depends_on_which_package_is_loaded`.

Is there any way to avoid writing a redirection function per function in my `utilities.R` file?

Comment: Can you explain in two bullet points why you cannot use a package?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel -- that didn't even occur to me! I don't really know anything about writing packages, but I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Dirk says, just use a package. In this case, put all your new `*.non.foo` functions in a new package, which is also called `foo`. Distribute this `foo` to your collaborators, instead of your in-house version. That way your utilities code can just be

```
functionname <- function(...) functionname.foo(...)
```

without having to make any checks at all.

Comment: Thanks for that - bundling them all into a package didn't even occur to me. If I did make a package, that means I won't need to call them `.non.foo` and `.foo` anymore, right? -- I can just call them all `functionname` and do either `library(fooUtilities)` and `library(nonFooUtilities)`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea: write a function that sets `f` to either `f.foo` or `f.non.foo`. It could be called in a loop, over all functions in a given namespace (or all functions whose name ends in `.foo`).

```
dispatch <- function(s) {
 if ( fooIsLoaded() ) {
    f <- get( paste(s, "foo",     sep=".") )
  } else {
    f <- get( paste(s, "non.foo", sep=".") )
  }
  assign( s, f, envir=.GlobalEnv ) # You may want to use a namespace
}
f.foo     <- function() cat("foo\n")
f.non.foo <- function() cat("non-foo\n")
fooIsLoaded <- function() TRUE
dispatch("f")
f()
fooIsLoaded <- function() FALSE
dispatch("f")
f()
```

A simpler solution would be to give the same name 
to both functions, but put them in different namespaces/packages.

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was initially after (although after reading the comments & other answer, I think a package may be the way to go).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds quite inefficient and inelegant, but how about

```
funify = function(f, g, package="ggplot2") {
 if(paste("package:", package, sep="") %in% search()) f else 
  { message("how do you intend to work without ", package) ; g}
}
  detach(package:ggplot2)
  foo = funify(paste, function(x) letters[x])
  foo(1:10)
  library(ggplot2)
  foo = funify(paste, function(x) letters[x])
  foo(1:10)
```